# Comparing dates in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am stuck in weird issue while comparing dates in ruby on rails.

here is what i am trying to do. i have parsed a file and selected a date into a variable `@timeinFile`. i am comparing this value to `created_at` of my `User`. here is the code:

```
@date=User.last.created_at
@arr.each do |i| 
    j=i.partition('(')[2]  
    @timeinFile=j.partition(')')[0].to_datetime
    if @date < @timeinFile    #Error: undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass
            @val='true'
    end
end
```

when i Comment if statement and paste values individually i get the following output

```
<p> <%= @date %> </p> ----------> 2013-08-05 09:16:33 UTC 

<p><%= @timeinFile.to_time %></p> -------------> 2012-10-02 12:00:00 UTC
```

anyone plz tell me what wrong i have done.

**Edit**

```
<a href="http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Recalls/2013/Fitness-Anywhere-Recalls-Early-Model-Suspension-Trainer-Devices-Due-to-Fall-Hazard/" target="_blank">Fitness Anywhere Recalls Early Model Suspension Trainer Devices Due to Fall Hazard</a> (Tue, 02 Oct 2012 12:00:00 GMT) Fitness Anywhere has received 570 reports of the strap length adjustment buckles breaking with 13 reports of injuries. TRX suspension trainers sold from 2006 through 2009. </p> </body> </html>
```

this is the line i am getting in @arr. next step was to partition with `(` and then with `)` to get date in round brackets...

Comment: Are you sure the error points to line with comparison?

Comment: It would be useful to see the contents of `@arr` when you get the error.

Comment: @MarekLipka yep it points to the same line :(

Comment: `@arr.compact.each` can you please try this  i think in @arr contains some `nil` values

Comment: @NeilSlater check the edit i made to original post. i am getting error on the statement i have pasted

Comment: @RajarshiDas check the edit in my original post. Thanks :)

Comment: That appears to be some HTML, perhaps related to what you intend to do? Answers will critically depend on the contents of the variable, including all the Ruby syntax. Could you show what `@arr.inspect` shows  *exactly* please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, why do you use `@timeinFile` in your code and `@timeonsite` in your tests?

```
#Error: undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass
```

basically means you are calling a method on a `nil` object, and I feel the error is triggered on the line BEFORE the `if` statement.

What happens when you put this check?

```
unless j.partition(')')[0].nil?
  @timeinFile=j.partition(')')[0].to_datetime
else
  @timeinFile = DateTime.now
end
```

If it doesn't give you an error you can go and find out why that value is `nil`.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the editing @Mischa, this morning my typing is quite wobbly.